# How to list out all MFI devies into the iOS app?

Tags: ios, external-accessory, mfi

I want to display the list of all MFI passed apple devices which are not paired before from iOS settings.

I can list out the connected devices using below code:

```
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager]

                               connectedAccessories];
```

So My Query is:

1. Can i scan all the available unpaired MFI devices using "External Accessories" framework in to the iOS app and then i can pair them from the iOS app.

Please help me for shorting this out.

Lots of thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, You can.

From iOS 6 EA Framework provides built-in bluetooth pairing function within app.

Check this:

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

You can also use filter parameters to filter your devices.

> But remember, if you send or receive data from device via MFI, you may need to add
>   protocol string into Info.plist on "Supported external accessory protocols"

Edit:

OK, I will list step by step of MFI world.

> 1.What above code is doing?

It pops up a small tableView to show all available Bluetooth devices.

> 2.How to pair?

Just click a cell shown in the table. It will automatically connect to device.

> 3.How to identify device is paired or not?

Check following code, You should understand what is it.

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error :%@", error);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"You make it! Well done!!!");
        }
    }];
```

> 4.Notification connect or disconnect?

Check the following notifications.

```
EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification
```

There are a lot things you can research on MFI, so it is better go through Apple documents and example code to understand it deeply.

Comment: Thanks brianLikeApple, I have used this method but now my app is crashing. Can you please explain this by step by step like: What code i should write in completion block? How the list of device will be displayed? How to pair the device? How i identify device is paired successfully? and if device is disconnected how app will notifies me that device is no longer be connected? Please help me i am going to accept your answer....

Comment: I have implemented this method but it is not showing any table view on the screen. I have put this code in -()viewDidLoad method. So i need to change any thing in this code?

Comment: No you don't need. Have you add EA Framework to your project? And also import .h Header? Or delay to call this methods after viewDidView using:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(showBTTalbe) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

Comment: @Nikh1414 I just want to modify my words that you can only show available device on the table, not all. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works with the "new" Scene-based mechanism. It's [broken since iOS13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70823487/415982)