# iOS How to name External Accessories protocol string

Tags: ios, external-accessory, ios-bluetooth, socketmobile

I use this [Socket Mobile web site](https://www.socketmobile.com/developers/mfi-approval/?languageRedirect=true) to fill **MFi** approval form.

My quiestion is about number

> 4. Any protocol strings you are using other than com.socketmobile.chs

I found information on page [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html) that describes:

> As part of your communication with the accessory manufacturer, you
>   must find out what protocols a given accessory supports. To prevent
>   namespace conflicts, protocol names are specified as reverse-DNS
>   strings of the form com.apple.myProtocol. This allows each
>   manufacturer to define as many protocols as needed to support their
>   line of accessories.

So should I specify this as `com.apple.myProtocol` or do I need to use `com.mywebsite.myProtocol`?

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it. Otherwise please give a reason why it is not accepted J

Answer (score 0):

I am working at MFI projects and have several projects on the App Store.

As far as I know, you should use `com.yourWebsite.yourProtocol` instead of `com.apple.protocol`, otherwise you cannot guarantee a unique protocol string on the earth.

Comment: ok got it and the protocol should be com.myWebsite.Bluetooth for example? any string?

Comment: Yes, it could be any string but need to be unique. It is better use a meaningful string like the function of that protocol. My case there are two protocols called uk.co.company.nmea and uk.co.company.vbox etc.

Comment: Hello @brianLikeApple , I have one doubt **yourProtocol** means, where can i get this? manufacturer will provide this for unique each device? or where you can register this protocol  **uk.co.company.nmea and uk.co.company.vbox**. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Haric If you are using third party hardware, you can always get protocols by EA framework, just try EA Demo code from Apple. If you are using your own company's hardware, then your company has to register it for the hardware. To communicate with hardware, you have to add those protocols to your project plist.

Comment: @brianLikeApple thanks for quick response, Actually i purchased **bluecreation** device BC127, And i am using Apple demo code ,and i am getting **error :Error Domain=EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)"** , and i am using protocol com.apple.p1, com.apple,p2  . Please suggest me how can i resolve this issues.

Comment: @Haric I have checked BC127, it has dual bluetooth mode - Classic bluetooth and BLE. To use EA framework, Classic bluetooth must have MFI chip inside. I cannot see anywhere that BC127 has MFI chip so I guess you have to use Core Bluetooth instead of EA framework?

Comment: @Haric I can get this error :Error Domain=EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)", If I click cancel button from bluetooth selector on my device. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20654221/833885

Comment: Thanks, @brianLikeApple , I was doing same i am getting response  **BTM: attaching to BTServer
 error :Error Domain=EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)",BTM: disconnection to service 0x00000001 on device "BC-XXXXX" XX:XX:XX:XX:1E:88 succeeded** And EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification
EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification was not calling, Any idea about this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149574/discussion-between-hari-c-and-brianlikeapple).