# How to search and connect nearby bluetooth device classic (Not BLE) on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I need to search nearby by bluetooth device those are classic Bluetooth (Bluetooth 2.1 or later). I searched a lot but there are only library and discussion about the BLE any guidance will help me a lot.

Comment: MFI bluetooth device can be found by iOS. For list of available devices check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654123/how-to-list-out-all-mfi-devies-into-the-ios-app/20654221#20654221

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't find them until you don't manually pair and connect them. In order to discover the already paired and connected ones, I use this:

```
import AVFoundation
func example() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth)
        if let inputs = session.availableInputs { ... } //should contain bluetooth devices aswell
    }
    catch { print("Failed to set category") }
}
```

`